# how to add latest webrtc sources to android project?

Tags: webrtc

So, there is existing webrtc project, that runs on latest libjingle(25dec 2015). And now, for support purpose, I need to update current version to latest from webrtc repo. How can I do that? I see there java files with c++ with headers in separate folders, have no idea what is going on there, even where files that I actually need, and how to implement that source to project. Is there any in-depth guide for that? Have anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC's project structure have changed a lot since last year. They are deprecating GYP in favor of GN, it is highly recommended to start from the beginning.

You can read the compilation guide for Android there: https://webrtc.org/native-code/android